# (Conventions) C# Class names

Tags: c#, naming-conventions, namespaces, conventions

I'm not too quite sure about what i should do about a grouped set of classes.

My situation: I have 11 classes that relate only to the class `Character.cs`, but all of those  classes (including `Character.cs` and `CharacterManager.cs`) are within the namespace `Models.Characters`.

Which is the more "proper" or preferred way of naming the classes:

(examples):

`CharacterDetails.cs`
`CharacterSprites`
`CharacterAppearance`
`CharacterClientRights`
`CharacterServerRights`

or:

`Details.cs`
`Sprites`
`Appearance`
`ClientRights`
`ServerRights`

(They're all noticed in `Models.Characters` (so eg. `Models.Characters.CharacterDetails`, `Models.Characters.Appearance`)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Personally for me it"depends".  Usually I would prefix everything with the word `Character` to keep things consistant, however if you have everything already under the `Character` namespace the Character prefix could seem redundant.

I could easily see going with the shorter convention of `Models.Character.[X]` if there never will be another class called `Details`, if there for instance could be `UserDetails` then `Details` and `UserDetails` could be confusing when looking back at the code weeks or months from now and I would personally prefer then the `CharacterDetails` option.

In the end it is your personal preference, what more accurately describes your domain, `Details` or `CharacterDetails`?

Answer (score 5):

Personally I'd stick with the second method as that is what namespaces are for: grouping related sets of classes. The first method is just making the class names longer with negligible benefits.

Answer (score 2):

It is really a personal preference.

I would favor

```
CharacterDetails
CharacterSprites 
CharacterAppearance 
CharacterClientRights 
CharacterServerRights
```

Because it is more readable.

You are typically going to have a using statement of

```
Models.Characters.Appearance
```

Unless you are going to do the full notation.

I would favor anything that would increase readability.  It might matter on the project and the team you are working with.  If it is just you than do what you like best and would help you maintain the code in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Your namespace already is grouping its classes under the `Characters` umbrella, so I would not name your classes with the `Character` moniker.

Answer (score 2):

There is probably no right or wrong answer here.  I find myself prefering your first style, but I have used the second style as well.  I think in this specific situation if I were a caller of your API I would find it easier to read code that used the first style.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you pick one and consistantly use that throughtout your code, then whichever one you choose is the right one.

My personal choice is your second option.  If your namespace is character, I see no reason to use the prefix character in the class name.

Comment: What's wrong with this answer it's perfectly valid, so why the downvote?   If you're going to downvote, at least have the common courtesy to say why.

Answer (score 1):

Think about ambiguity that may be created by naming class. For example if I have a class called "Thread" denoting "CharacterThread" (hypothetical) and if some other class uses two namespaces

Models.Characters
System.Diagnostics

I will have to fully qualify the Thread name everytime I use it ... which can be a pain sometimes