# c# Class Names - Convention on how to name classes

Tags: c#, namespaces, naming-conventions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [(Conventions) C# Class names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760449/conventions-c-class-names)

I use Entity framework (or even with Nhibernate or linq to sql) you usually have a series of entity classes that get passed around a solution. I usually, have these classes in a VS Project called [SolutionName].Data

At some stage these will be used by another class which might carryout some business logic prior to saving and deleting them. In this situation I then have these action classes in a project called [SolutionName].Core

I have seen some developers suffix these classes with Logic or Manager e.g. RegistrationManager which would then have a Save(), Delete(), Update(). A prime example of this is the open source NopCommerce.

Some put them into a  folder called Bll but leave the name unchanged e.g. the namespace would be [SolutionName].Core.Bll with a class in that called Registration. They would then reply on the namespace distinguishing whether this is a database entity or a business logic class.

The question is how should I be naming classes? Should I just suffix everything with Logic/Manager/Service or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 2):

I've always liked these:

http://10rem.net/articles/net-naming-conventions-and-programming-standards---best-practices

Comment: This is very generic and doesn't fully answer the question that I have above.

Answer (score 1):

You should not suffix everything and thats all.

You have to create different projects not folders for different layers.

Comment: So the [SolutionName].Core and [SolutionName].Data approach with the Class names staying as they are e.g. Registration class in 2 different projects is ok?

Comment: This is ok. 1) You can resolve it by namespace. 2) Sometimes you will add two or three assemblies where will be types with same names and this is normal situation. 3) Sometimes you will generate types for some reasons(like for mapping) and this types can have names which will dublicate existing one in you project or referenced assemblies and this is absolutely normal situation, thats why namespaces used.